# Campo retornando data em padrão brasileiro e o outro em americano em typescript. Como validar?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, data

Estou com uma problema de validação de campo, em que quando a data retorna da minha API em formato Americano é feito a conversão para o Brasileiro como abaixo:

```
formatDate(date: string) {
if (!date) {
  return '-'
}
const [year, month, day] = date.split(/[^\w\s]/gi);
return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
```

}

Porém quando o meu service retorna a data em formato Brasileiro a mesma muda para o padrão Americano rsrsrsrs.... sendo que era pra ficar em formato Brasileiro.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão de como validar isso pra que quando venha padrão brasileiro, continue brasileiro?

Comment: Me parece mais um problema do seu serviço que de angular ou algoritmo. Seria melhor se ela mandasse  algo como {day:xx, month:xx, year:xxxx}

Answer (score 0):

Da para fazer funções separadas tipo assim:

```
custom.convertDatePortuguestoSql=function(date){
    if(date != null && date != ""){
        var s = date.split("/");
        var ano = s[2];
        var mes = s[1];
        var dia = s[0];
        return ano+"-"+mes+"-"+dia;
    }
    else return '';
};  

custom.convertDateSqltoPortugues=function(date){
    if(date != null){
        var s = date.split("-");
        var ano = s[0];
        var mes = s[1];
        var dia = s[2];
        return dia+"/"+mes+"/"+ano;
    }else{
        return '';
    }
};
```

Ai você chama cada qual for sua necessidade, mas realmente me parece que o seu problema não é na função em si e sim na forma como esta funcionando o restante do seu código, ai teria que nos mostrar mais códigos para analisarmos.